# Reading ISA logs files with awstats

Tags: awstats, isa-server

I keep getting dropped or currupt records but no new ones.

```
Phase 1 : First bypass old records, searching new record...
Searching new records from beginning of log file...
Jumped lines in file: 0
Parsed lines in file: 29978
 Found 5706 dropped records,
 Found 24272 corrupted records,
 Found 0 old records,
 Found 0 new qualified records.
```

I'm using Microsoft Internet Security and Acceleration Server 2006
I am saving my logs in the w3c format. This is what is written at the top of my log files.

```
#Fields: c-ip   cs-username c-agent date    time    s-computername  cs-referred r-host  r-ip    r-port  time-taken  cs-bytes    sc-bytes    cs-protocol s-operation cs-uri  s-object-source sc-status   s-cache-info    rule    FilterInfo  cs-Network  sc-Network  error-info  action  GMT Time    AuthenticationServer
```

I'v tried this but it doesn't work.

```
LogFormat = "%host %logname  %ua %other %time2 %other %other %other %other %other %other %bytesd %other %other %method %url %other %code %other %other %other %other %other %other %other %other %other"
```

or

```
LogFormat = 2
```

Other settings i'v set

```
LogFile="/test/ISALOG_20120111_WEB_000.w3c"
LogType=W
LogSeparator=" "
```

Any ideas?